# Comparing Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am just trying to get some data and re-arrange it.
Here is my dataset showing foods and the scores they received in different years.
What I want to do is find the foods which had the lowest and highest scores on average and track their scores across the years.

[image]

The next part is where I am a little stuck:
I'd need to display the max and min foods from the original dataset that would show all the columns - Food, year, Score. This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```
menu[menu.Food == Max & menu.Food == Min]
```

Basically I want it to display something like the below in a dataframe, so I can plot some graphs (i.e. I want to then make a line plot which would display the years on the x-axis, scores on the y-axis and plot the lowest scoring food and the top scoring food:

[image]

If you guys know any other ways of doing this, please let me know!

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is expected output correct?

Comment: Thank you so much Jazrael! :) That was super helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select first and last rows per `year` by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with invert mask and chain by `|` for bitwise `OR`, filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[~df['year'].duplicated() | ~df['year'].duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Solution with **groupby**:

```
df1 = df.groupby('year').agg(['first','last']).stack(1).droplevel(1).reset_index()
```

If need minimal and maximal per `year`s:

```
df = df.sort_values(['year','food'])
df2 = df[~df['year'].duplicated() | ~df['year'].duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Solution with **groupby**:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('year')['Score'].agg(['idxmax','idxmin']).stack()]
```